# google app engine golang, driver: bad connection

Tags: mysql, google-app-engine, go

I have some code that is working on the local GAE server but once I publish it to GAE it throws the error "driver: bad connection".

Below code generates a new *sql.DB:

```
func NewDb() (*sql.DB, error) {
  cloud := os.Getenv("dbcloud")
  local := os.Getenv("dblocal")
  if appengine.IsDevAppServer() {
    return sql.Open("mysql", "root@tcp("+local+":3306)/dbo")
  }
  return sql.Open("mysql", "root@cloudsql("+cloud+")/dbo")
}
```

In my app.yaml I have the following:

```
env_variables:
  dbcloud: 'projectid:instancename'
  dblocal: 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx'
```

It seems to return a new *sql.DB correctly but once I start using prepared statements is when things start to break.

```
db, err := NewDb() // err is nil
stmt, err := db.Prepare("INSERT INTO dbo.Users (Id) VALUES (?)") // err is driver: bad connection
```

I've been fighting with this for an hour now and i'm probably doing something very stupid any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Are you using go-sql-driver (`"github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql"`) or mymysql driver (`"github.com/ziutek/mymysql/godrv"`)?

Comment: github.com/go-sql‌​-driver/mysql, do I need to use github.com/ziutek‌​/mymysql/godrv with GAE?

Comment: No, both work well with Cloud SQL, but they require different syntax to define the data source. Yours look fine however, are you sure user is `root`, and project id and instance name are correct?

Comment: Yep only user is currently root (I connect to the Cloud SQL instance via IP using the local GAE server and it works fine) and have checked the project id / instance name multiple times they're identical so I can't see that being the issue.

Comment: Are your app and Cloud SQL instance in the same region? Have you granted your app access to the SQL instance?

Comment: Yeah both are us-central and they're in the same project so they have access by default I believe, going off of the access control of the SQL instance: "App Engine authorization All apps in this project are authorized by default. To authorize apps in other projects, follow the steps below."

Comment: See this page how to grant access: [Connecting from Google App Engine](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/app-engine-connect) (note: different steps for first and second generation instances).

Comment: Yeah I had seen that before asking here I am currently using Gen 2 which the first step is: "If your application is in the same project as your Cloud SQL instance, you can proceed to step 2." which just gives you the connection code? The only thing I don't understand is that sql.Open doesn't cause an error, but trying to use db afterwards does?

Comment: That is normal. `sql.Open()` just validates its arguments, but it does not open a connection. For that you may use `DB.Ping()`. See this answer for details: [Why does sql.Open() return nil as error when it should not?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32345607/1705598)

Comment: Hey @icza have found the issue! I needed to change my dbcloud env_variable to include my region even though they're both in us_central? So now it goes 'projectid:regionname:instancename' and works... Thank you so much for your time though even though it was just a silly mistake by me!

Comment: Glad you solved your issue. Please post your solution as an answer so others can benefit from it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up needing to change my dbcloud variable to include the region of the SQL server changing it from:

```
'projectid:instancename'
```

To:

```
'projectid:regionname:instancename'
```

No idea why I need to do this as it's not in the docs of https://github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql but is all working now!